# How to Add The Animation Splash screen in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to add the splash screen to my app, I have some questions:

1. It will be possible using the splash screen class?
2. We need any another view controller class for that?
3. Can we set it using the any another way, like we use xib of splash screen?

Comment: Are you referring to the very first screen shown? You can setup that screen in storyboard, also known as the "Launch Screen". If you refer to screens beyond that, it is custom and yes you would new another view controller, or some other third party lib.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment.
We are adding the launch screen, similar to that, I want to add it. But it will be Animated. So how can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It will be possible using the splash screen class?

I believe it's not possible from that specific class but there are other ways around

> We need any another view controller class for that?

Yes it's necessary in order to customize your own splash screen

> Can we set it using the any another way, like we use xib of splash
>   screen?

just don't put any design to your splash screen view and redirect your app to a view controller where you can customize things the way you want and to animate in your starting of view you can visit this link as a startup point: [How To Create an Uber Splash Screen](https://www.raywenderlich.com/133224/how-to-create-an-uber-splash-screen)

Answer (score 0):

To make your own animated splash screen, you set the default splashscreen to be All black color. Then, you set your custom launch screen as the first view to be loaded. Then on this view, you can do anykind of animations you need in viewDidAppear or similar delegate.